# Realtek rtl8188ftv wifi usb disconnects immediately

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek

I recently purchased a USB wifi for my Ubuntu PC.
The device is Zebronics USB150WF1 (rtl8188ftv).

After plugging it, it worked fine in windows but was not recognised by linux, although it was showing in the `lsusb` output.

After following a guide on different linux forum, i installed the driver for this wifi usb.

The driver repository is - https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

Now, the wifi driver is recognised by the system, and it can also scan for nearby wifi networks, but when selecting any wifi to connect to, it just can't connect.

It just tries to connect to it and then immediately disconnects. Unfortunately i can't find the solution to this problem in any other forum. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after sorting through many posts, I managed to fix it:

Follow the steps:

1. Install Drivers from https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu

follow all the commands given on the github page.

2. Run `modinfo rtl8188fu`, match input with below image.

[image: modinfo output]

3. Run `echo "options rtl8188fu rtw_ips_mode=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf`
4. Finally reload the driver with `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188fu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8188fu`
5. Now reboot the system and try to connect.
   [image]

Source- https://medium.com/@kaw411gh0st/how-to-fix-rtl8188fu-cant-connect-to-any-network-in-linux-f0bf1a9e5e4c